# Data structure for efficient string matching against many patterns

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, pattern-matching, string-matching, trie

I am looking for an efficient data structure that allows string to pattern matching. The patterns follow a regex like syntax but allow recursion. They contain optionals, choices and recursion/wildcard symbols. Some examples of patterns are:

```
how many * (are coming|came) to (the)? party
(drunk|sober)? people
annoying *
```

These patterns would match the following strings:

```
how many drunk people are coming to the party
how many people came to party
how many annoying drunk people are coming to the party
```

And would fail for those ones:

```
how many are coming to the party  <-- expected something else after 'many'
drunk sober people  <-- has to be either 'drunk' or 'sober' but not both
```

The syntax is basically the same as for regex. Except that the `*` expects another matched pattern at that location. `()` is a simple group. `()?` is an optional group. `(choice1|choice2)` is a choice group.

**Some more info about patterns/inputs**:

- There will be about 10'000 patterns
- Most patterns are shorter than 200 characters
- Patterns should support unicode format (although most of them will probably only contain ASCII chars)
- The input will be a list of sentences
- Each sentence should match a pattern (and it's nested patterns)
- Sentences are usually shorter than 200 characters
- Most sentences contain less than 5 different patterns (an exception
  are sentences with arithmetic expressions which could contain a lot
  more patterns)
- Most sentences are correct and successfully match a pattern
- Validating whether a sentence makes sense or not is not yet important

**Requirements**:

- The data structure should be memory efficient (10MB is probably ok,
  100MB is not)
- The data structure should support addition of patterns at runtime (deletion is not important, addition does not have to be crazy fast)
- The data structure should not take too long to build (seconds)
- Matching should be reasonably fast, above 10'000 sentences / second is the target

**Naive Solution 1**
Store all patterns in an array and try to match one after the other until we succeed or reach the end of the list. This gets painfully slow with recursion. So not an option.

**Naive Solution 2**
Building a prefix/patricia/... trie from all the possible patterns and include some special nodes for wildcards. This is better but every optional/choice group creates additional patterns. This makes the tree "explode" very quickly. Especially because it will create many branches that are different close to the root but very similar closer to the leaves.

**More Complicated Solution**
Creating a trie from words in the pattern and assign them a unique index. Using the trie we can translate the input string to a sequence of integers. But then I need some way to match the integers back against the patterns. Not really sure how to do that.

I feel like there should be a nice way to solve this sort of problem. I guess that a tree representation is the right choice but I can't find any algorithm/data structure that fits the task. Has anyone dealt with a similar problem and some suggestions for me?

Note: This is just a toy project for me. I am not looking for some production quality tool and I also don't really care how long it would take me to implement it. Just curious if a nice solution exists out there.

Comment: have you checked https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String-searching_algorithm#Algorithms_using_a_finite_set_of_patterns ?

Comment: Consider building a Finite State Machine: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine.

Comment: @juvian Yes I did, but these algorithms are for exact string matching.

Comment: @JimMischel State machine is an option, but I am looking for something more specific.

Comment: @JimMischel FSMs won't help because they recognize regular languages only. Here recursion is allowed, so the language to recognize is not regular.

Comment: I see the recursion mentioned, but don't see any examples of it.

Comment: @JimMischel The `*` denotes the place in a pattern where a nested pattern is expected. This can either be some other pattern or the pattern itself. In the case of addition you would have the following pattern: `* + *`. With sentence fragments it is the same.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a special case of [context-free grammars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar#Context-free_grammars). Unfortunately, your definition does not restrict it further to [deterministic context-free grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_context-free_language) as ambiguities are possible. So your best bet is [Earley parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earley_parser) or [CYK algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CYK_algorithm), as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the links! I will definitely have a look at them.

Comment: I had a look at the sources and I have two concerns. First, the grammar size will be huge and it seems that the algorithms just try to match one pattern after the other (which is what I wanted to avoid). And second, it does not look like you can add additional rules to the grammar at runtime. But I am pretty sure that I could implement that somehow.